# Writing a @JsonParam annotation to map Json field in request body to method args

Tags: java, json, rest, annotations, jersey

I'm using Jersy Rest, one of the requirement being is variable number of input from client to REST endpoint, with a JSON document that have N number of fields. I have been asked to write a `@JsonParam` annotation and to map the input json to Rest Endpoint method arguments. 
Something like

```
public ResultWrapper addToCart(@JsonParam(key="cartId") String cartId)
{
....
}
```

Where input JSON might be

```
{
 cartId:1233,
 custId:123213,
 itemId:3344
}
```

I have jackson in classpath and gave a solution where the entire input JSON is mapped to a **java.util.Map** and getting the values with map.get(key). But they are insisting on a @JsonParam as in map there is not type safety and i have to parse each of the input to the corresponding type.

I need some pointer on how to write a annotation processor for **@JsonParam** that will work with jersy.

Comment: Which version of Jerse are using? Basically you need to create an InjectableProvider for your annotation which would extract the method parameter value from the http request.

Comment: @Alexey im using jersy 1.17. Its part of Broadleaf commerce so not sure if i can upgrade to 2.x

Answer (score 2):

Find below an example code based on the Jersey's 1.x InjectableProvder which inject a value to a parameter from a JSON string posted to a resource method.

The annotation class:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface JsonParam {
    String key();
}
```

The provider class:

```
@Provider
public class JsonParamProvider implements InjectableProvider<JsonParam, Parameter> {

    @Override
    public ComponentScope getScope() {
        return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public Injectable<Object> getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, final JsonParam jsonParam, Parameter parameter) {
        return new AbstractHttpContextInjectable<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object getValue(HttpContext c) {
                // extract the entity one per request                   
                Map<?, ?> entity = c.getRequest().getEntity(Map.class);
                if (entity != null) {
                    // then store it a request property
                    c.getProperties().put("requestEntity", entity);
                } else {
                    entity = (Map<?, ?>) c.getProperties().get("requestEntity");
                }
                if (entity == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                return entity.get(jsonParam.key());
            }

        };
    }

}
```

The resource method declaration:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String foo(@JsonParam(key = "a") String param1, @JsonParam(key = "b") Integer param2) {
    return "Params: " + param1 + " " + param2;
}
```